# Vertical drop-down menu on the subpage in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, menu, menuitem, submenu

I have a problem with the menu.
He wants to make a menu that is being developed.

I want to add a class li 'open' and 'active'.

Menu:

1. Category1 url: ( http://name.com/category1 )

   - Subcategry1-1 url: ( http://name.com/category1/subcategory1-1 )
   - Subcategory1-2   url: ( http://name.com/category1/subcategory1-2 )
   - Subcategory1-3  url: ( http://name.com/category1/subcategory1-3 )
2. Category2 url: ( http://name.com/category2 )

   - Subcategory2-1 url: ( http://name.com/category1/subcategory2-1 )
   - Subcategory2-2 url: ( http://name.com/category1/subcategory2-2 )
   - Subcategory2-3 url: ( http://name.com/category1/subcategory2-3 )
3. Category3  url: ( http://name.com/category3 )
4. Category4 url: ( http://name.com/category4 )

Code menu:

```
<nav class="sidebar__menu">
    <ul class="sidebar__menu__list">
        @if ($menu_items_mops->count())
        @foreach ($menu_items_mops as $k => $menu_item)
        @if (($menu_item->page_id && is_object($menu_item->page)) || !$menu_item->page_id)
        @if ($menu_item->children->count())
        <li  class="{{ ($menu_item->url() == Request::url())?' active':'' }}">
            <a href="{{ $menu_item->url() }}" title="{{ $menu_item->name }}" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">{{ $menu_item->name }}</a>
            <ul  class="dropdown-menu">
                @foreach ($menu_item->children as $i => $child)


                <li class="{{ ($child->url() == Request::url())?'active':'' }}">
                    <a class="hyphenate" href="{{ $child->url() }}" title="{{ $child->name }}">{{ $child->name }}</a>
                </li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </li>
        @else
        <li class="{{ ($menu_item->url() == Request::url())?' active':'' }}"><a href="{{ $menu_item->url() }}" title="{{ $menu_item->name }}">{{ $menu_item->name }}</a></li>
        @endif
        @endif
        @endforeach
        @endif
    </ul>
```

Where url is category1/category2/category3/category4 active in menu works well but when url is subcategory active/open menu not work.

The code responsible:

```
<li  class="{{ ($menu_item->url() == Request::url())?' active':'' }}">
```

I tried to do something like this but it does not work:

```
<li class="{{ request()->is($menu_item->url().'/*') ? 'active' : '' }}">

<li  class="{{ (Route::is('$menu_item->url().*') ==  $menu_item->url()) ? ' active':'' }}">
```

Maybe someone knows how to compare the address with menu_item-> url and add a class where url is menu_item->url/*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't something like this work ?

Category:

```
<li class="{{ (\Request::is($menu_item->url()."/*") ) ?' active':'' }}">
```

Sub Category

```
<li class="{{ (\Request::is($child->url())) ? 'active':'' }}">
```

Comment: Did not work. He does not add a class to category and subcategory ;/

Comment: what does `$menu_item->url()` and `$child->url()` return?

Comment: $menu_item->url return category, $child->url() return subcategory

Comment: but the full qualified url? http://whatever.com/category1/subcategory1-1/ ? with the / or without in the end?

Comment: I don't now why {{dump (\Request::is($menu_item->url()."*") )}} return false...
Url is same.

Comment: and {{\Request::url()}} returns exacly the same url? weird

Comment: Something that might be harder but also a solution, is passing id's of the categories and sub-categories currently selected on all views, as variables and instead of validating the url, validating if the active id is equal to the one currently being drawn.

Comment: Thanks Serfio. I added a small script. that is works. Sometimes simple solutions are very hard to come by.

Comment: That much is true. Glad to have helped